# Custom SQL Order By Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by

I would like to create a custom order in my sql query, just changing one rows position.

This is my current sql results -

```
Age Category    Female  Male
-------------------------------

30-39           2772    3193
40-49           1587    2246
50-65           990     3718
Over 65         176     3487
Under 30        1359    1500
```

I would like them to sort like this, with the 'under 30' at the top -

```
Age Category    Female  Male
-------------------------------

Under 30        1359    1500    
30-39           2772    3193
40-49           1587    2246
50-65           990     3718
Over 65         176     3487
```

Here is my code -

```
SELECT DISTINCT


CASE 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN 'Under 30'
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49' 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN '50-65'
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN 'Over 65'
END as 'Age Category',


CASE 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 30 AND 39 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 40 AND 49 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm') 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 50 AND 64 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
END as 'Female',


CASE 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 30 AND 39 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 40 AND 49 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm') 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 50 AND 64 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
END as 'Male'


FROM NAME N1
WHERE [STATUS] ='A' AND 
  MEMBER_TYPE IN ('MM') AND
  (
   CASE 
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN 'Under 30'
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49' 
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN '50-65'
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN 'Over 65'
   END
  ) IS NOT NULL

group by datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()), member_type
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a manually calculated SortOrder column, then order by that and [Age Category]

```
SELECT DISTINCT


CASE 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN 'Under 30'
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49' 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN '50-65'
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN 'Over 65'
END as 'Age Category',


CASE 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 30 AND 39 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 40 AND 49 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm') 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 50 AND 64 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
END as 'Female',


CASE 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 30 AND 39 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 40 AND 49 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm') 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate())BETWEEN 50 AND 64 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
END as 'Male'

-- Newly inserted code starts


CASE 
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN 1
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 65 THEN 3
    WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN 2
END as 'SortOrder',


-- Newly Inserted Code Ends

FROM NAME N1
WHERE [STATUS] ='A' AND 
  MEMBER_TYPE IN ('MM') AND
  (
   CASE 
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) <= 30 THEN 'Under 30'
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49' 
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 THEN '50-65'
        WHEN datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) >= 65 THEN 'Over 65'
   END
  ) IS NOT NULL

group by datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()), member_type
-- newly inserted code
ORDER BY SortOrder, [Age Category]
```

Comment: @RyanGillooly - Though it does still rely on you use of literally dozens of sub-queries making this very resource hungry, which is not at all needed.

Comment: @CoolWilly's answer is far simpler than mine, and it'll work.  I'm going to keep this out there as an example because a computed sort order column is sometimes necessary, but in this case, I'd go with his answer, not mine.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it enough to just add an order by?
    order by datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate())

Otherwise, maybe you could also change the age categories to "30 and under" and "65 and above"

*Edit* This query may be easier / less repetitive. By the way, the BETWEEN clause is inclusive, so you should use < 30 instead of <= 30 (and > 65 instead of >= 65) to make sure those ages aren't counted twice.

```
SELECT 'Under 30' AS 'Age Category',
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) < 30 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm') AS 'Female',
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) < 30 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm') AS 'Male'
UNION ALL
SELECT '30-39',
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
UNION ALL
SELECT '40-49',
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 40 AND 49 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
UNION ALL
SELECT '50-65',
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
    (select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) BETWEEN 50 AND 65 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Over 65',
(select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) > 65 and gender ='f' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
(select count(*) from name n1 where datediff(YYYY,n1.birth_date,getdate()) > 65 and gender ='m' and status ='a' and member_type ='mm')
```

Comment: Better yet, order by birth_date desc.  By the way, if anyone thinks this should have been a comment, at the time it was posted, @CoolWilly did not have a high enough rep to do that.

Comment: either way, both datediff(YYYY,birth_date,getdate()) and birth_date would have to be included in my select statement, which then brings back more results than i would like

Comment: Are you sure, have you tried it? To my knowledge, columns specified in an ORDER BY clause do not need to be specified in the SELECT clause.
(But I only checked in a simpler query.)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a table to join on this becomes so much easier.

```
CREATE TABLE dim_age_band (
  id            INT,
  title         VARCHAR(32),
  ordinal       INT,
  bound_lower   INT,
  bound_upper   INT
)

INSERT INTO dim_age_band SELECT 1, 'Under 30', 1,  0,   30;
INSERT INTO dim_age_band SELECT 2, '30-39',    2, 30,   40;
INSERT INTO dim_age_band SELECT 3, '40-49',    3, 40,   50;
INSERT INTO dim_age_band SELECT 4, '50-65',    4, 50,   66;
INSERT INTO dim_age_band SELECT 5, 'Over 65',  5, 66, 1000;

SELECT
  MAX([dim_age_band].[name]                            )   AS age_band_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [name].[gender] = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS female,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [name].[gender] = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS male
FROM
  dim_age_band
LEFT JOIN
  name
    ON  [name].[birth_date] <= DATEADD(YYYY, GetDate(), [dim_age_band].[bound_lower])
    AND [name].[birth_date] >  DATEADD(YYYY, GetDate(), [dim_age_band].[bound_Upper])
    AND [name].[STATUS]      = 'A'
    AND [name].MEMBER_TYPE  IN ('MM')
GROUP BY
  [dim_age_band].[id]
ORDER BY
  MAX([dim_age_band].[ordinal])
;
```

**EDIT :**

Note that I'm also *not* using DATEDIFF() on the `[birth_date]` field.  Instead I'm running that calculation on today's date and the age band boundaries.  This means that it becomes possible to use indexes to search the `[name]` table by the `[birth_date]`; if such indexes exist.

**EDIT :**

CTE Version...

```
WITH
  dim_age_band (name, ordinal, bound_lower, bound_upper)
AS
(
            SELECT 'Under 30', 1,  0,   30
  UNION ALL SELECT '30-39',    2, 30,   40
  UNION ALL SELECT '40-49',    3, 40,   50
  UNION ALL SELECT '50-65',    4, 50,   66
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Over 65',  5, 66, 1000
)
SELECT
  MAX([dim_age_band].[name]                            )   AS age_band_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [name].[gender] = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS female,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [name].[gender] = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS male
FROM
  dim_age_band
LEFT JOIN
  name
    ON  [name].[birth_date] <= DATEADD(YYYY, GetDate(), [dim_age_band].[bound_lower])
    AND [name].[birth_date] >  DATEADD(YYYY, GetDate(), [dim_age_band].[bound_Upper])
    AND [name].[STATUS]      = 'A'
    AND [name].MEMBER_TYPE  IN ('MM')
GROUP BY
  [dim_age_band].[id]
ORDER BY
  MAX([dim_age_band].[ordinal])
;
```

Inline View version:

```
SELECT
  MAX([dim_age_band].[name]                            )   AS age_band_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [name].[gender] = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS female,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [name].[gender] = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS male
FROM
(
            SELECT 'Under 30' AS name, 1 AS ordinal,  0 AS bound_lower,   30 AS bound_upper
  UNION ALL SELECT '30-39'    AS name, 2 AS ordinal, 30 AS bound_lower,   40 AS bound_upper
  UNION ALL SELECT '40-49'    AS name, 3 AS ordinal, 40 AS bound_lower,   50 AS bound_upper
  UNION ALL SELECT '50-65'    AS name, 4 AS ordinal, 50 AS bound_lower,   66 AS bound_upper
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Over 65'  AS name, 5 AS ordinal, 66 AS bound_lower, 1000 AS bound_upper
)
  AS dim_age_band
LEFT JOIN
  name
    ON  [name].[birth_date] <= DATEADD(YYYY, GetDate(), [dim_age_band].[bound_lower])
    AND [name].[birth_date] >  DATEADD(YYYY, GetDate(), [dim_age_band].[bound_Upper])
    AND [name].[STATUS]      = 'A'
    AND [name].MEMBER_TYPE  IN ('MM')
GROUP BY
  [dim_age_band].[id]
ORDER BY
  MAX([dim_age_band].[ordinal])
;
```

Comment: i cant create any tables unfortunately in our environment

Comment: @RyanGillooly - Then use an inline view, or CTE.